# VB6 Routine to use the Current Shell Directory

Tags: vb6

I am trying to write a VB6 program to run from the Windows command line to look for certain files in the current command line directory and act on them.

I have tried no path, I have tried curdir, but I always get a file not found.

Is there a way to get a VB6 program to access a file based on the current windows command line directory?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to show your code or no one can help you.

Comment: Does `Path` help you get the path of the batch file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the VB6 program is launched from within a Windows **Cmd** prompt, it will automatically use the directory from which it is launched as its current working directory, and will open files without a fully specified path in that directory.  Note that this is the directory *from which it is launched*, not the directory in which the executable resides.

To test and demonstrate this, I created an extremely simple program.  I started the VB6 IDE, and created the default project which opens with a single form **Form1**.  On that form I placed a single button **Command1**, and within the **_Click()** event I placed the single line:

```
MsgBox "Current directory is: " & CurDir
```

Running this program from within the IDE produced the result

```
Current directory is: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98
```

since that's where the IDE executable lives.  however, compiling it and running the executable from a **Cmd** window -- or double-clicking on it in Explorer -- produced the expected result:

```
Current directory is: C:\Data
```

(I have my system set up uniquely, with my **Documents** directory pointed to **C:\Data** for historical reasons related to my workflow.)  Running it from another directory also gave the expected result

```
C:\Data\Projects
```

even though the executable **Project1.exe** still resided in the **C:\Data** directory.

So, in short, I believe that VB6 is working as you expected it to, and most likely your program's inability to open a file is do to some other issue.  As @StayOnTarget mentioned, if you could show your code someone here might be able to point out the problem.